# Can/Should I add CRAN package to my work published?

Tags: cv

I've developed a package for R and it is added to CRAN. Should I add it to my work published, although it isn't peer reviewed for content, or should I just add a single line that mentions the package?

Comment: Also note that if you'd like a peer-reviewed article relating to the package, you could submit a paper on its usage and benefits to places like  [the Journal of Statistical Software](http://www.jstatsoft.org/) or [the R journal](http://journal.r-project.org/). You could also potentially publish a paper about the package in a more field specific journal as well if it's interesting to that field: for example [PLoS Computational Biology](http://journals.plos.org/ploscompbiol/) publishes R packages.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I would definitely consider including this in your CV. It's scientific work, and you [expect people to cite your package](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/27921/4140).

---

It would make sense to put this under a separate heading, so your publication list contains "Peer-reviewed publications" and "Non-peer-reviewed publications" - this way, you don't give the impression of trying to inflate your publication list by sneaking in some non-reviewed stuff.

If at a later date you have authored multiple R (or other) packages and perhaps published other non-reviewed material, you could subdivide the "Non-peer-reviewed publications" by splitting off software into its own section.

Comment: I'd agree that "software in its own section" is the right way to go.  Keep in mind that you can include software packages in an NSF biosketch under "synergistic activities" rather than in the limited list of up to 10 publications.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, definitely out this in your published works. I also agree with @Stephan Kolassa but instead of "Non-Peer-Reviewed", depending on your field of study you could probably list is as a technical publication.